# xml doesn't decode specific character

Tags: xml, decode, encode, utf

I have this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<lingua>
<lang name="DE">
<translation name="Testo_Home"><![CDATA[<p>In den Hügeln</p>]]></translation>
</lang>
</lingua>
```

The problem is that in the html pages carettere special ü appears, even if I change the code in this way

```
<translation name="Testo_Home"><![CDATA[<p>In den H&uuml; geln</p>]]></translation>
```

the result of the words is always this
Hgeln without ü

```
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Comment: If you take the time to read it, this will help a lot: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Answer (score 0):

Change the encoding in the `<?xml ... ?>` tag:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

See http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_encoding.asp

Comment: if I change to ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 does not display anything on the site!

Comment: Hm... Make sure that the file is actually saved in utf-8 as well. There should be a setting in your text editor when you save the file.

Comment: Is the file transformed via XSLT or how do you display it on the site? If you have a url I can take a look, can't promise that I will see what the problem is though...

Comment: ok now it works but the problem remains the same as before the special character is not displayed!
very strange

Answer (score 0):

You should use `UTF-8` as the encoding for the XML file as well (most text editors have an option to save in a different encoding). And also change:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
```

to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

to reflect that change.